# Why does the Terminal keep showing "^[[2~" randomly?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal, samsung, usb-installation

When I'm using the Terminal (only there), it keeps showing `^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~` at random times, even when I am neither pressing any key at all on my keyboard nor even touching the trackpad. On average, I would say I get 5 lines full of that input in 20 seconds (although sometimes I can be around 2 minutes without that problem).

The only relevant post I have found so far is the one titled [Why the terminal shows “^[[A” “^[[B” “^[[C” “^[[D” when pressing the arrow keys in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384040/why-the-terminal-shows-a-b-c-d-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys). If the arrows are responsible for those symbols, which key is responsible for `^[[2` ?

What is causing the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: FWIW, `^[[2~` represents the Insert key, per [this page under "VT220-Style Function Keys"](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-VT220-Style-Function-Keys). (`CSI 2 ~` means `^[[2~`)

Comment: Did you try a different keyboard?

Comment: Can any one tell me, "how to turn off this ^[[2 command repeating?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a bit of trial and error, on my system I found that the <kbd>Insert</kbd> is `^[[2~`. You can check this in a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (to turn on Verbatim mode), then pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd>. It's possible the key is faulty and sending in keypresses randomly. I have heard of programs which inhibit sleep by simulating keypresses (perhaps Caffeine?) so that might also be a cause.