# Unable to perform tasks on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, dell, gnome-terminal, 64-bit

I have this weird problem that whenever I type any command on the terminal, I am interrupted by `^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~` and on the other hand whenever I press Shift it copies data from browser or any texts impromptu and pastes it. I am finding it very difficult to perform any task

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Terminal keep showing "^\[\[2~" randomly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094233/why-does-the-terminal-keep-showing-2-randomly)

Comment: No.  It doesn't work - Both the link above and the link within