# When I open Ubuntu terminal "~~~~" and "^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~" characters are coming nonstop . How can I get ride of this?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, gnome-terminal

While using the Terminal exclusively, I frequently encounter the occurrence of `~~~~~~~~~~` and `^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~` characters appearing randomly. This happens even when I am not actively pressing any keys on my keyboard.

[image: terminal showing reoccuring characters]

I tried to reset my `.bashrc` file to stop this, but it didn't work.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094233/why-does-the-terminal-keep-showing-2-randomly), but not a solution to fix the issue.

Comment: Does it stop when you unplug your keyboard?

Comment: i'm using laptop

Comment: By the way, the linked answer you put there does have an answer.  An application like Caffeine was causing the problem.  Have you booted to a Live USB to maybe test that it isn't a hardware issue?  And if it doesn't do it from there, you will probably have to eliminate software one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Terminal keep showing "^\[\[2~" randomly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094233/why-does-the-terminal-keep-showing-2-randomly)